# meteor deps not reactive

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I've spent days trying to figure out why the template is not updating. Please help!  Below is the relevant code.

```
@Listings = new Meteor.Collection 'listings'

class Map
  constructor : (map_canvas=null, map_options=null) ->
    @listings = Listings.find()
    @observer = new Deps.Dependency()

  viewable_listings : ->
    @observer.depend()
    @listings

  set_listings : (listings) ->
    @listings = listings
    @observer.changed()
```

So viewable_listings() is set as a template helper

```
Template.listings.helpers
  listings : map.viewable_listings()
```

But when changing the value of @listings, the template does not update.  For example

```
map.set_listings Listings.find({}, {limit:3})
```

Does absolutely nothing.  No reactive from the listings template.  However changing values in the db via Listings.remove(...) works as usual.

Comment: What happens if you change your helper to `listings: -> map.viewable_listings()`? If that doesn't fix it, I'd recommend creating a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/).

Comment: Wow, that was it!!!  Well that makes sense.  Apparently, wrapping it in a function is what makes these helpers a computation.  I simply assumed that the whole helper object was a computation.  Thanks again, I'll check out meteorpad.  Feel free to post your answer for marking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listings` helper isn't a function so dependency tracking won't work. The helper will always be the result of the first call to  `map.viewable_listings()`. That value happens to be a cursor so it makes sense that something would render, but would not update when you want it to. Give this a try:

```
Template.listings.helpers
  listings: ->
    map.viewable_listings()
```